# How to add a custom ID to a bootstrap collapse and read line items from a text file into them? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently i have a program that receives user input via a text input. This text input is then transferred to a .txt file which is then later on read into a collapsible div within my view. Each input is considered a 'category' (each category is the heading of its own collapsible), and each category is assigned a primary key, starting from 0 upwards. Secondly, the user can input a sub-category which will then be displayed within the collapsible under the respective category header. As shown in the image below;

[image]

'University Work' being the Category input,

'Assignment 1' being the Sub-Category (Item) input.

I would like to assign a Foreign Key to the Sub-Category (Item) which will then obviously relate to the Primary Key of the respective Category. That being said, i would like to be able to enter multiple Sub-Categories (Items) per Category, each Sub-Category (Item) obviously having the same Foreign Key as long as they are assigned to the same Category.

Currently my issue(s) are as follows, if i am to have multiple Categories, all collapsible's would open no matter which Category i am clicking on. I assume this has something to do with the 'foreach' loop that i am currently using.. Secondly, i am very stuck on how i could proceed from here onward. I can't possibly expect a full solution to my problem, however some general guidance would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note; The user adds a Sub-Category (Item) by clicking on the 'plus' icon in the image above, this takes the user to a separate view where he/she can then input a Sub-Category (Item) for the Category the 'plus' icon is related, this Sub-Category (Item) is then put into a .txt file, alongside its own Primary Key, as well as the Foreign Key of the respective Category to which it is assigned.

Below is the controller i use for reading in the inputted Categories;

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Category(string categoryDescription)
        {
            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            var numberOfLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(dataFile).Count(); /* Records the ID (PK) of each inputted category */

            var textFileData = categoryDescription + "," + numberOfLines + Environment.NewLine;

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(dataFile, textFileData);

            return View();
        }
```

Following that is the second controller and view in which i read and display the inputted categories;

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            Category passCategory = new Category
            {
                result = "",
                delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
                userData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile)

            };           

            return View(passCategory);

        }
```

View:

```
<div class="categoryList">

        @Model.result
        @if (Model.result == "")
        {
            foreach (String dataLine in Model.userData)
            {

                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        @dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[0]
                    </a>

                    <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Items","Items")'" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="fas fa-plus secondaryPlusIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="far fa-edit secondaryEditIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="far fa-trash-alt secondaryDeleteIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                </p>

                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3 collapsible" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]">
                        <!-- This is where i wish to display the added items per each category... -->
                    </div>
                </div>

            }

        }
    </div>
```

I have already created a controller for reading the Sub-Categories (Items) into a .txt file (It follows a very similar structure to that of the Category controller (Category ActionResult)..

I hope i was able to provide sufficient information and code in order to give an understanding of what exactly i am trying to accomplish.. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!